# Gmail Contextual Gadget Trigger when Composing new Email

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

How should I trigger a Gmail contextual gadget when the user hits 'COMPOSE'?

Answer (score 3):

"A contextual gadget can neither be triggered while composing an email nor while submitting an email. It can only be triggered when a user chooses to open an email either from his Inbox or sent mail."

copied from [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/VDrVtTtcVDA)